# Not entering into the database, 0 errors coming up

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to make a photo gallery, so far with the upload screen, it comes up saying it worked, when I check for errors it comes out with nothing and yet it doesn't add anything to MySQL. Help?

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$photo_types = array(
  'image/pjpeg' => 'jpg',
  'image/jpeg' => 'jpg',  
  'image/gif' => 'gif', 
  'image/bmp' => 'bmp', 
  'image/x-png' => 'png' 
); 

$pics=$_FILES['filename'];
$caps=$_POST['captions'];
$cout=0;

while($cout <= count($pics)) 
{
    if(isset($pics[$cout]) && $pics[$cout] > 0) 
    { 
        if(!array_key_exists($pics['type'][$cout], $photo_types)) 
        {  
            $finals .= 'File ' . ($cout + 1) .   ' is not a photo<br />';
        } 
        else
        {

$typo=$pics['type'][$cout];
$extnz=$photo_types[$filetype];
$filename="$new_id.$extension";
mysql_query("
  INSERT INTO photos ( 
    filename,
    caption, 
    album 
  ) VALUES (  
    '" . $filename . "', 
    '" . $caps[$cout] . "',
    '" . $_POST['album'] . "' 
  )
") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_commit($connection);

            copy($pics['tmp_name'][$cout],$image_dir . '/' . $filename);

            $size=GetImageSize('photos/' . $filename);

            if ($size[0]>$size[1])
            {
                $tw=100;
                $th=(int)(100*$size[1]/$size[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                $tw=(int)(100*$size[0]/$size[1]);
                $th=100;
            }

            $im="C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16";
            exec("$im/convert -geometry " .  "{$tw}x{$th} " . "$image_dir/$filename photos/tb_$filename");
            }
    } 
$cout++;
}
echo "worked!";
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: why are you calling `mysql_insert_id` at the top, there?

Comment: apply your insert query straightly in phpmyadmin then check is it through any error

Comment: and actually, as a debug technique, try printing the query you're actually running (variables populated etc.) to the screen...and show us what the final query looks like.

Comment: @Mark because I was doing it weird earlier, but whenever I went back to fix up the code I didn't remove the line.

Comment: @Mark Elliot I tried the commit thing, do you think you can find the problem?

Comment: Replace mysql_query with echo and edit your question to show the query that's printed to the screen, with that information, I, or someone else, might be able to help.

Comment: @Mark Elliot, sadly nothing? I also tried it with print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the problem was I was doing

`if (isset($pics[$cout]))`

so to fix this I did

`if (isset($pics['name'][$cout]))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `COMMIT` to actually commit the transaction to the database.

Comment: Vanquez-Abrams I added `mysql_commit($connection);` right after and it still didn't add, also I updated the code to show it all, can you see what I did wrong?